# ActiveMQ not delivering/dispatching persistent messages on queues

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

I am using ActiveMQ v5.10.0  and having an issue almost every weekend where my ActiveMQ instance stops delivering persistent messages sent on queues to the consumers. I have not been able to figure out what could be causing this.

While the issue was happening I tried following things:

- I added a new consumer on the affected queue but it didn't receive
  any messages.
- I restarted the original consumer but it didn't receive any messages after the restart.
- I purged the messages that were held on the queue but then messages started accumulating again and broker didn't deliver any of the new messages. When I purged the expiry count didn't increase neither the dequeue and dispatch counters.
- I sent 100 non-persistent messages on the affected queue, surprisingly it received those messages.
- I tried sending 100 persistent messages on that queue, it didn't deliver anyone of them, all the messages were held by broker.
- I created a fresh new queue and sent 100 persistent messages and none of them was delivered to the consumer whereas all the non-persistent messages were delivered.

The same things happen if I send persistent or non-persistent messages from STOMP producers. Surprisingly all this happened only for queues, topic consumers were able to receive persistent as well as non-persistent messages.

I have already posted this on ActiveMQ user forum: http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Broker-not-delivering-persistent-messages-to-consumer-on-queue-td4691245.html but no one from ActiveMQ has suggested anything.

The jstack output also isn't very helping.

More details:
1. I am not using any selectors, message groups feature
2. I have disabled producer flow control in my setup

I want some suggestions as to what configuration values might cause this issue- memory limits, message TTL etc.

Comment: This may be clutching at straws since I'm a Websphere MQ guy but are you committing the transactions (assuming transactionality is a feature of ActiveMQ)? The reason I ask is a recent requirement I had to fix up messages that were in an in-doubt state within MQ - they were in the queue but no process could touch them. Other than that, you'll need some more specific product knowledge than I have.

Comment: We use spring DMLC for consuming messages with sessionTransacted=true and don't use any external transactions. Spring should do the commits automatically is my understanding.
Moreover the setup runs fine on other days, its just that on the weekend night it starts showing this behavior which requires a broker restart. May be some special code is running due to some threshold breach which causes broker to go into bad state. But i am not acquainted enough to know where to look.

Comment: What is the state of the counters on that queue? In particular, enqueueCount, dispatchCount, dequeueCount and queueSize. Can you also let us know what the values of CursorMemoryUsage and CursorPercentUsage are, and what size messages you are sending on that queue?

Comment: Hi Jake, During the time issue was happening- the dequeue and dispatch count were not increasing. The enqueue count kept on increasing as new messages arrived and the queue size was equal to (dequeue-enqueue) count and kept on increasing as messages were enqueued.
I checked for unacknowledged messages count on consumer side but it was 0. which made me suspect that consumer is not receiving messages and which is what i observed with new consumer creation.

Comment: @Xabhi have you found the solution for your problem. Please let me know , I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Navnath We weren't able to find the cause of it. However, we upgraded to ActiveMQ v5.11.1 and haven't seen this issue yet. What version are you using?

Comment: @xabhi thanks for reply , we are using 5.7.0 version.